# mySQL delete--trigger the safe update mode error while using a key column

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-delete

I tried to delete the entries in table1 which also appear in table2.
code is the primary key for both table1 and table2.
And I use the following query:

```
delete from table1 where table1.code = any(select code from table2);
```

However, I got the following error msg:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a `WHERE` that uses a `KEY` column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor and reconnect.

But my understanding is I have already used the `WHERE` with a `KEY` column.

Is there any advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using any restriction clause in your subquery.

Comment: Thanks. However, I want to delete everything from Table2. So I did not use any restriction in the subquery. And if I run the subquery alone, it is fine with no problem.